# React Native Text Selection (Highlight text in different colors) HTML view and custom menu

Tags: react-native, highlight, textselection

Help, I am having trouble completing the required functionality:

1. Highlight text (Select text and highlight in colors).
2. Make notes in the selected text.

I already tried almost all of the libraries available (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cn-quill/v/0.7.6 etc), but had no success. Ideally, I would like to hire someone to implement the required functionality.

I have attached a screenshot to understand the functionality.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoxvl.png)

Answer (score 0):

a little late but maybe this helps:

used:
"@alentoma/react-native-selectable-text"

to create this:

https://github.com/Domth13/React-Native-Highlight-Text